# reply to sender mail php script

Tags: email-headers, reply, mail-form

I have been looking for a mailform script and came up with his. Works fine, but just this matter: when I reply to the received email, I am replying to myself, whilst I would like to reply automatically to the mailadres of the sender.

```
<?php
$to = "MY@MAILADRES.COM";
$subject = "mail via website";
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$comments = $_POST['message'];
$message = "
name: $firstname $lastname
email: $email

subject: $onderwerp

message: $comments
";
  $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
     $headers = "From: MY@MAILADRES.COM\r\n".
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
     $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
        "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $message . "\n\n";
     foreach($_FILES as $userfile)
     {
        $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
        $type = $userfile['type'];
        $name = $userfile['name'];
        $size = $userfile['size'];
        if (file_exists($tmp_name))
        {
           if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
           {
              $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
              $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
              fclose($file);
              $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
           }
           $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
              "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
              " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
              "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
              " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
           $data . "\n\n";
        }
     }
     $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
   echo "Thanks for getting in touch.<br>Your message wil get my full attention.<br>I     will get back to you soon.";
else
   echo "Error in mail.<br>Please try again.";
?>
```

What should I change in this code, please?
I added these (seperately):

`$headers .= "From: Contact Form (Domain.com) <no-reply@domain.com>\r\n";`

`$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_REQUEST['email']."<". $_REQUEST['email'].">\r\n"`

But none seem to work. I got this code to work with and all good, except for the reply-to.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The whole code looks like you should better refactor it to use any existing mailing library like Symfony Mailer, SwiftMailer, phpMailer

Comment: The RFC specifies `Reply-To:` as the header to reply to but e.g. Outlook seems to ignore it. Forging the `From:` header seems like the only way to get Outlook to play nice. (More reason to avoid Outlook, but I seem to fail to reach the hearts and minds of many naïve Microsoft customers.)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Clarification is in the edited post.